# write token into file in java

Tags: java, io, tokenize

I have tokenization code and i want to write the result into file .txt so i can use the file to remove all the punctuation

```
public static void tokenization() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    String msg;

    int numberOfTotalTokens =0;
    int numberOfMessages = 0;

    String data = "E:\\Data\\SMSSpamCollection.txt";

    FileInputStream fisData = new FileInputStream(data);
    BufferedReader readBufferData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fisData));

    try{
        while ((msg =readBufferData.readLine()) != null) {
            int numberOfTokens = 0;
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(msg);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("Before: "+msg);

            System.out.print("After : ");
            while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                msg = tokens.nextToken();
                String msgLower = msg.toLowerCase();
                numberOfTokens++;
                numberOfTotalTokens++; 
            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Total Tokens: "+numberOfTokens);
            System.out.println("\n");
            numberOfTokens++;
            numberOfMessages++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total Tokens: "+numberOfTotalTokens);
        System.out.println("Total Messages: "+numberOfMessages);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

the result of this is code is set of tokens:
example:
my
name
is
stackoverflow

that set of tokens need to write into file .txt
how i can write that into file .txt

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain exactly what's wrong with the code you've got. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: you need to tokenize,remove punctuation(or stop word) and then write in .txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the changes to your code with comments. With this code you can write one token per line to a file `output.txt` using `BufferedWriter`.

Some remarks:

- your code does some basic tokenization ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)) and doesn't take care of *stop words* like punctuation for instance
- `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is kept for backwards compatibility but it is recommended to use `String.split` with regular expressions instead
- for more advanced tokenization you can use the Apache Lucene library

Hope it helps!

```
public static void tokenization() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

String msg;

int numberOfTotalTokens =0;
int numberOfMessages = 0;

String data = "E:\\Data\\SMSSpamCollection.txt";
// create a new output file output.txt
String outfilename = "E:\\output.txt"; 
File file =new File(outfilename);
file.createNewFile();

FileInputStream fisData = new FileInputStream(data);
BufferedReader readBufferData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fisData));

// create a buffer writer tokDataB
FileWriter tokData = new FileWriter(outfilename,true);
BufferedWriter tokDataB = new BufferedWriter(tokData);

try{
    while ((msg =readBufferData.readLine()) != null) {
        int numberOfTokens = 0;
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(msg);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("Before: "+msg);

        System.out.print("After : ");
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            msg = tokens.nextToken();
            String msgLower = msg.toLowerCase();

            // write one token per line to output file
            tokDataB.write(msgLower);
            tokDataB.write("\n");

            numberOfTokens++;
            numberOfTotalTokens++; 
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Total Tokens: "+numberOfTokens);
        System.out.println("\n");
        numberOfTokens++;
        numberOfMessages++;
    }

    // close output writer
    tokDataB.close();                    

    System.out.println("Total Tokens: "+numberOfTotalTokens);
    System.out.println("Total Messages: "+numberOfMessages);
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error Exception: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

}